# Gnuplot: scale ytics to a certain range

Tags: gnuplot

I have setup a plotting script on gnuplot and I wish to re-scale the y-axis tics in the range of 0.0 up to 1.0
In the atached image below

[image]

You can see that the graph at `y=0.3` meets `x=0`. I wish to re-scale the axis in order to fit everything, like a 'zoom out'.

I have tried playing around with

`ytics (0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0)` but that does not make the trick. I was also trying to re-format them into percentages, namelly 0% - 100% but that didn't work either.

Whats the correct syntax of the command?

Comment: What is your data? what is your actual plotting code? Have you checked the manual or basic tutorials? What about `set yrange[0:1]`?

Comment: Hey there @theozh . It works! Thanks, I've been stuck in reading the ytics. But can I also specify the step with the range? I see that the valid args are ```{ [{{<min>}:{<max>}}] {{no}reverse} {{no}writeback} } | restore``` so I guess this must be done in combination with the ```ytics```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `help yrange` or `help xrange`.

You can specify the step size via `set ytics`. Check `help ytics` or `help xtics`.

```
set yrange[0:1]
set ytics 0.1
```